# How to click the Submit button which has no id and name using mechanize?

Tags: mechanize, ruby-1.9.3, mechanize-ruby

Find the below HTML code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="TARGET" value="www.example.com"/>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="Resume"/></noscript>
</form>
```

How to click the Submit button which has no id and name using mechanize?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer of such scenarios, the code is below:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
#---some more codes are here, the main trick started at below.
button = Login_form.button_with(:name => 'Submit')
loggedin_page = Login_form.submit(button)
loggedin_page=agent.submit(loggedin_page.forms.first, loggedin_page.forms.first.buttons.first)
```